# How to load different css files depending on screen size media query | Next.JS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, web-applications, frontend

I want to load different CSS files depending on the user's screen size, one for mobile, one for tablets, one for desktop and sometimes one for widescreens. The reason I want to do this it to optimize for speed and minimize the unused CSS in each screen size. The way I do create the CSS files follows this:
\> All the core stylings (think of colors, border sizes, hover effects, active effects, padding, font sizes etc) will be put into the phone css (min-width: 0px)
\> Everything that will be changed to tablet screens (think of container heights, flex-directions, grid-template-columns etc) will be put to the tablets css (min-width: 600px)
\> Anything that will be changed to desktop will be put into its own file (min-width: 1024px), and same thing happens with widescreens (min-width: 1280px)

I have previously done so in previous projects using the <link> element and specifying the screen sizes.

I want to do the same thing with Next.JS, where I load the needed css files for each screen size, but I don't know how to do it. Writing manually on the head of the pages and putting <link> with the required media queries feels wrong, as I feel like there's a better, more recommended way for Next.JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in **many** ways, if you want to use css as most frameworks do then inside your component or page folder you can have a 'styles.css' or 'anyName.css' and write your styles just like any css with corresponding class name. After this, all you have to do is `import styles.css` inside of the component you'd like to use it in!

**OR** If you'd like to use a dynamic wrapper (less work) and add it to each head in your pages without doing it manually, you can do this in many ways as well such as creating the styles and adding them to a layout wrapper! **Below are 3 different examples**, if you want more ways or elaboration on a specific approach just let me know, and I'll update this.

### Example 1, dynamic head w/ layout

next/head component to dynamically insert  tags into the  of your pages based on the screen size

```
import React from 'react';

const DynamicCSS = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/path/to/mobile.css"
        media="(min-width: 0px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/path/to/tablet.css"
        media="(min-width: 600px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/path/to/desktop.css"
        media="(min-width: 1024px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/path/to/widescreen.css"
        media="(min-width: 1280px)"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default DynamicCSS;
```

create layout wrapper:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import DynamicCSS from './DynamicCSS';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <DynamicCSS />
      </Head>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

usage of layout wrapper / dynamic css:

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

---

### Example 2 : css file with layout wrapper

this can also be used with multiple css layouts and take a type as prop to switch between them such as themes

```
import React from 'react';

const DynamicCSS = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/css/mobile.css"
        media="(min-width: 0px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/css/tablet.css"
        media="(min-width: 600px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/css/desktop.css"
        media="(min-width: 1024px)"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="/css/widescreen.css"
        media="(min-width: 1280px)"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default DynamicCSS;
```

create layout again

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import DynamicCSS from './DynamicCSS';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <DynamicCSS />
      </Head>
      <div className="container">{children}</div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .container {
          margin: 0 auto;
          max-width: 800px;
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

use layout:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my Next.js project.</p>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

### Example 3 - direct import (super simple & my fav)

create css to handle everything then import it(and make sure classnames correspond):

```css
/* responsive.css */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/* Mobile-specific styles */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    /* Tablet-specific styles */
  }
}

/* Desktop-specific styles */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    /* Desktop-specific styles */
  }
}

/* Widescreen-specific styles */
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .container {
    /* Widescreen-specific styles */
  }
}
```

usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../public/css/responsive.css';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my Next.js project.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

### Hope this helps!

**Reminder**: If this solved your question make sure to mark your question as answered and/or upvote if it is helpful! Thank you!

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Great. I was not even aware of a media attribute of `<link>`. So not Next.js related but plain HTML. Never was versatile on frontend. :-) But anyhow. I would focus on other optimizations unless one has huge CSS files for each media query. Probably, background image could be such a use case. Next.js client/server component optimization can be quite challenging, at least for beginners and for me.

Comment: You're welcome and glad this helped! Happy coding! :-)